# var_dump help needed

Tags: php

The coding below seperates the $state data, I need help putting the var_dump info into $dat1 $dat2 and $dat3 where needed

```
if($en['country'] == 'US'){
   if ($_POST['locus'] == ''){$err .= 'Please select and fillin your locale.<br>';}
   $state = $_POST['locus']; // separate: NEW YORK, NY 10011
   preg_match("/(.*)\,\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+([\d]+)/", $state, $parts); 
   var_dump($parts);

} elseif($en['country'] == 'CA'){
   if ($_POST['locca'] == ''){$err .= 'Please select and fillin your locale.<br>';}
   $state = $_POST['locca']; // separate: PARADISE, NL A1L1P1
   preg_match("/(.*)\,\s+([A-Z]{2})\s+([\S]+)/", $state, $parts); 
   var_dump($parts);

} elseif($en['country'] == 'GB'){
   if ($_POST['locuk'] == ''){$err .= 'Please select and fillin your locale.<br>';}
   $state = $_POST['locuk']; // separate: LONDON, H9
   preg_match("/(.*)\,\s+([\S]{2})/", $state, $parts); 
   var_dump($parts); 
}
```

Comment: pocketfullofcheese is correct; var_dump is more of a debugging tool.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$parts[0] will have the whole string that is matched
$parts[1], $parts[2], and $parts[3] will have the data you want:

```
$dat1 = $parts[1];
$dat2 = $parts[2];
$dat3 = $parts[3];
```

Comment: if you need to show those variables, you can just echo them to the screen: echo $dat1; echo $dat2;, etc.  You can add any additional HTML if this is going on a page or ad echo "\n"; to get a newline.

Answer (score 1):

You could do

```
ob_start();
var_dump($parts);
$dat1 = ob_get_flush();
```

Answer (score 1):

What for? var_dump is not ment to be used this way. It is purely debugging function and this is why it doesn't have an output to a variable. You should use other functions.

Use variables:

```
$part[0] ... the whole expression of the reg. exp. is stored in this variable
$part[1] ... content of the first subexpression
$part[2] ... ...
$part[3]
```

You should also avoid of redundancy in your code. $err variable may be set in before the first condition.

Comment: how would i fix the redundacy with $err?

Comment: Just put the line:

    $err .= 'Please select and fillin your locale.<br>';

before first "if" statement and delete the rest othe assigning to the $err